# KeyListener not accepting function as override

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a JFrame called frame.
I initialize it like this:

```
    frame = new JFrame("Game"){{
        setSize(500, 600);
        setFocusable(true);
        setUndecorated(true);
        add(g);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                player.keyPress(e.getCharacter().toCharArray()[0]);
            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
        });
    }};
```

I get an error from the keylistener saying that I need to override its functions. I tried adding an @Override annotation, but it just tells me there's nothing to override. What have I done wrong?

Comment: maybe you are forgetting to add the imports ? are you sure that you have the import java.awt.event.KeyEvent and the import java.awt.event.KeyListener; ?

Comment: Say you're self a world of pain and problems and use the key bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I was using netbeans auto-import and I imported the wrong keyEvent (from javafx)